# pytest not showing unit test failures when failing coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, pytest

I set my coverage to 100% for my test in with pytest-cov.

`py.test -s --tb short --cov-config .coveragerc --cov $(project) $(TARGET)`

`.coveragerc` file looks like this:

```
[report]
fail_under = 100
show_missing = true
precision = 2
exclude_lines =
    # Don't complain about debug-only code
    def __repr__

    # Don't complain about placeholders
    raise NotImplementedError

    # Support pragma: no cover
    pragma: no cover

    pass
```

This works well except for one problem: When the coverage dips below 100%, it doesn't show any unit test failures. This is really annoying because it means I have to manually change the `fail_under` line to below 100, fix all the errors, and then move it back to 100.

Comment: How are you integrating coverage with pytest?

Comment: That definitely doesn't sound right.  Provide some more details.

Comment: I'm using pytest-cov: http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html